# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence; para quimica

Tags: python, array, funciones

Estoy tratando de resolver este codigo y cuando voy a ejecutarlo, en la variable "k" me sale el value error me podrian ayudar a solucionar este error, le he dado cabeza y nada que he podido.
Este es mi codigo:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
#Fenol benceno y tolueno
T=310.15
P= 3.0
R= 0.8134
Pc= ([61.30,48.98,41.06])
Tc= ([694.3,562.2,591.8])
Pr = [P / Pc[i] for i in range(len(Pc))]
Tr = [T / Tc[i] for i in range(len(Tc))]
x=[0.3,0.2,0.5]
w= ([0.444,0.210,0.262])
gi=([0,0,0])
A = [0.42 * (Pr[i] / Tr[i]**2) for i in range(len(x))]
B = [0.125 * (Pr[i] / Tr[i]) for i in range(len(x))]


def fn(zmix):
    Aij = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    p = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    q = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    r = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    Bmix = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    Amix = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    Vc = np.zeros((len(x),len(x)))
    Tcm = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    Pcm = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    Prm = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    wm = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    Trm = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    k = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    # Bi= np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        Vc[i] = (R * Tc[i] / Pc[i]) * (0.290 - 0.085 * w[i])
        Vc[j] = (R * Tc[j] / Pc[j]) * (0.290 - 0.085 * w[j])
        k[i, j] = [1 - 8 * (Vc[i] ** 0.167 * Vc[j] ** 0.167 / Vc[i] ** 0.33 + Vc[j] ** 0.33) ** 3]     #Aqui mismo es 
        Tcm[i, j] = ((1 - k[i,j] ) * ((Tc[i] * Tc[j]) ** 0.5))
        Trm[i, j] = T / Tcm[i, j]
        Prm[i, j] = P / Pcm[i,j]
        wm[i, j] = (w[i] * w[j]) ** 0.5
        Aij[i, j] = 0.42 * (Prm[i, j] / Trm[i, j]**2)
        Amix[i,j]=x[i]*x[j]*Aij[i,j]
        Bmix[i, j] =x[i] * B[i]
        p[i, j] = -1 - Bmix[i, j]
        q[i, j] = Amix[i, j]
        r[i, j] = -Amix[i, j] * Bmix[i, j]
        
return np.sum(zmix) **3 + np.sum(p * zmix ** 2) + np.sum(q * zmix) + np.sum(r)

# Minimización de la función objetivo
zmix = optimize.minimize(fn, 0.5,bounds=[(0,1)]).x
```

Al ejecutar el ciclo for me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

```
<ipython-input-9-596676abbc44> in fn(zmix)


    36             Vc[i] = (R * Tc[i] / Pc[i]) * (0.290 - 0.085 * w[i])
     37             Vc[j] = (R * Tc[j] / Pc[j]) * (0.290 - 0.085 * w[j])
---> 38             k[i, j] = [1 - 8 * (Vc[i] ** 0.167 * Vc[j] ** 0.167 / Vc[i] ** 0.33 + Vc[j] ** 0.33) ** 3]
     39             Tcm[i, j] = ((1 - k[i,j] ) * ((Tc[i] * Tc[j]) ** 0.5))
     40             Trm[i, j] = T / Tcm[i, j]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Como pueden ver aqui nos dice el nombre del error, pero hasta donde se ve todo parece estar bien; sera algun problema de agrupacion en cuanto a parentesis o corchetes?

Comment: Estás intentando añadir una fila de varias columnas en una única posición `[i, j]` de `k` y es por ello que `numpy` te devuelve ese error.

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio. El mensaje parece claro, ¿has probado a cambiar los corchetes (que son los que definen una secuencia) por paréntesis (que agrupan una serie de operaciones que devuelven un número)?